Confusion about JT gravity from extremal black holes, and AdS v. dS
I am currently reading section 2 of [1], trying to understand the motivations behind Jackiw-Teitelbom (JT) gravity.
It is known that the near-horizon geometry of an extremal RN black hole is $AdS_2\times S_2$.
This is also seen in [1] at the level of the action:
$$
S = \frac{1}{16\pi G}\int \mathrm{d}^4x \sqrt{|g|}\left(R_g - \frac{l_p^2}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\right)
$$
with the following ansatz:
$$
\mathrm{d}s^2 = h_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^i\mathrm{d}x^j + {\Phi(r,t)}^2\mathrm{d}\Omega^2
\\
F_{\phi\theta} = -F_{\theta\phi} = P\sin{\theta}
$$
with all other components of $F$ equal to 0, and $i=0,1$.
As far as I understand, this field strength tensor corresponds to that of a magnetic monopole.

After some work, the action takes the form
$$
S \sim \int \mathrm{d}^2x \sqrt{|h|}
  \left( \Phi^2 R_h + \lambda (\partial\Phi)^2 - U({\Phi^2}/{d^2})\right) 
$$
for specific choices of $\lambda$ and the dilaton potential $U(\phi^2/d^2)$. Most importantly, the dilaton potential is
$$
U(\Phi^2/d^2) = \frac{1}{2}\Phi^{-2}Q^2 l_p^2 - 2.
$$
The first term here comes from the field strength tensor:
$$
F^2 = F_{\phi\theta}F^{\phi\theta} = 2Q^2 \Phi^{-4}.
$$
Expanding around a constant value $\phi_0$, extremality of the action then yields
$$
R = \frac{1}{d^2} U'(\phi_0/d^2)
$$
When $U'$ is negative, like in the example above, $R$ is also negative, and we have a (nearly) $AdS_2$ space as expected.
However, if we instead consider an electric monopole ($F_{tr} = Q^2 \Phi^{-2}$), we get
$$
F^2 = 2h^{tt}h^{rr}F_{tr}F_{tr} = -2 Q^2 \Phi^{-4}
$$
(assuming $h^{tt}h^{rr} = -1$, which I think is reasonable considering the RN case).
This has a sign flip compared to the magnetic case, consequently leading to a $dS_2$ space instead of $AdS_2$ like before.
This is very strange to me, since magnetic and electric charges enter the RN metric in the same way (see Carroll, P.255). At the level of the metric, the near-horizon limit should then yield $AdS_2$ regardless.


It seems that it is magnetic monopoles which are usually considered in the literature, but I can't comprehend why the electric case would not lead to $AdS_2$ as well. Any help would be appreciated.

References:

[1]: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08482

Hello, Thank your for bringing this up. But can you explain why your $F^2$ changed its sign when you boosted from magnetic field to electric field? $F^2$ is a Lorentz invariant and thus there might be some error in your duality transformation from $B$ to $E$.

@timebeforespace I didn't intend to boost the electric field into a magnetic field, but rather consider two different scenarios altogether. However, since a hypothetical magnetic charge appears in the metric the same way as the electric charge, the (near-horizon) geometry is unchanged. I am confused why I get a conflicting answer at the level of the action when following the procedure in [1].
What boost/duality transformation could I perform to go from the magnetic monopole to an electric monopole?

Thank you for your response. Sorry, I am still unclear about your derivation. Can you clearly show all the steps? I see typos above and it would be great if you could show the whole derivation and then we can see why it doesn't work. It has to work, we know that.
